# Download File with JSON response as redirection via WebRequest

Tags: json, vb.net, pdf, download, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am struggling to find a way to donwload files via WebRequest.
The API is quite easy. So I have for example following address:
https://eprel.ec.europa.eu/api/products/tyres/381324/labels?format=PDF
In this case a label is shown in the browser.

With `/labels` I can download a zip package.
With `/labels?noDirect=true&format=PDF` the response will be a `200 OK` with the content containing the URL of the resource (`\{address:label or fiche URL}`).

With the code:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://eprel.ec.europa.eu/api/products/tyres/381324/labels?noRedirect=true&format=PDF")
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
Console.WriteLine(response)

Using dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responsefromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine(responsefromServer)
End Using
```

I get the OK response but not the URL for downloading the label.
Also if I use just `/labels?format=PDF` I am not able to just safe the shown PDF.

I also tried Selenium but this solution is way to slow. So I would prefer to stick with the WebRequest.

Maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The API has a 2-way response, based on the URI of the request:

- If your URI is a query, as
  https://eprel.ec.europa.eu/api/products/tyres/381324/labels?format=PDF
  the response is a JSON that specifies a URL fragment that replaces the query, to build a new URI to the direct resource.
  But it also changes the `WebResponse.ResourceUri` address to this exact location. Don't use the `?noDirect=true` option.
- If you specify a direct address, as https://eprel.ec.europa.eu/label/Label_381324.pdf
  the ResponseStream will contain the data to download.

**Note**: this is a binary file, you cannot use a `StreamReader` to read binary data.

Here two methods that allow to download your PDF files as a byte array.
`GetPDFResourceAsync()` takes an Uri in the form of a query, gets the response and then call the second method, `GetPDFResourceDirectAsync()`, passing the `WebResponse.ResourceUri` it received from the server.

If you want to us the query URI, call `GetPDFResourceAsync()`, if you want to use the direct resource Uri, just call `GetPDFResourceDirectAsync()`.

The `InitializeWebRequest()` method is an utility method that initializes the HttpWebRequest. Without it, `GetPDFResourceAsync()` would not work, since the server expects a `User-Agent` header set and a Compression method (otherwise you get garbage).

Now, these methods return a byte array (the PDF file data).
You can store it to disc using the [File.WriteAllBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes) method. E.g.:

```
' Indirect method, using a URI query
Dim pdfBytes = Await GetPDFResourceAsync(New Uri("https://eprel.ec.europa.eu/api/products/tyres/381324/labels?format=PDF"))
' Direct method, using a resource URI
Dim pdfBytes = Await GetPDFResourceDirectAsync(New Uri("https://eprel.ec.europa.eu/label/Label_381324.pdf"))

Dim pdfFilePath = Path.Combine("[Some Directory]", "Label381324.pdf")
File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilePath, pdfBytes)
```

**The worker methods**:
In case you don't want / can't use `async` methods, just remove `async` and `await` from everywhere (method names included) and you'll have synchronous code.

```
Public Async Function GetPDFResourceAsync(resourceUri As Uri) As Task(Of Byte())
    Dim request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(resourceUri)
    InitializeWebRequest(request)
    Using locResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(Await request.GetResponseAsync(), HttpWebResponse)
        If locResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Return Await GetPDFResourceDirect(locResponse.ResponseUri)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Using
End Function

Public Async Function GetPDFResourceDirectAsync(resourceUri As Uri) As Task(Of Byte())
    Dim request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(resourceUri)
    InitializeWebRequest(request)

    Dim buffersize As Integer = 132072
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(buffersize - 1) {}

    Dim dataResponse = DirectCast(Await request.GetResponseAsync(), HttpWebResponse)
    If dataResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        Using responseStream As Stream = dataResponse.GetResponseStream(),
            mStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Dim read As Integer = 0
            Do
                read = Await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                Await mStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read)
            Loop While read > 0
            Return mStream.ToArray()
        End Using
    End If
    Return Nothing 
End Function

Private Sub InitializeWebRequest(request As HttpWebRequest)
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8")
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache")
End Sub
```